# Cannot run Linphone android source

Tags: linphone

I've cloned the following Github repo from Linphone
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

When attempting to build and run the project the app crashes on launch with the following exception

```
10-19 12:10:57.509 3358-3358/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.linphone.tools.OpenH264DownloadHelper', referenced from method org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.createOpenH264DownloadHelper
10-19 12:10:57.719 3358-3358/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: org.linphone, PID: 3358
                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.linphone.tools.OpenH264DownloadHelper
                                                     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.loadOpenH264(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:101)
                                                     at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.createLinphoneCore(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:116)
                                                     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:661)
                                                     at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:297)
                                                     at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:191)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2574)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: I fixed this. Make sure you clone the github repo properly. When cloned properly you'll get all the libraries. The total size of the clone will be a little over 1GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error clone the linphone github repo properly. Do no use the download button in GitHub, instead use the clone command from GitHub shell or the clone option from GitHub desktop